# Grant permission issue in azure active directory for Power Bi embedded

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to provide permissions to user in Azure portal in App Registration process but while providing permissions for active directory Getting below error message.

```
{"errorCode":"Authorization_RequestDenied","localizedErrorDetails":
{"errorDetail":"PowerBITANMYAPP is requesting permissions, which you are 
not authorized to grant. Contact your administrator, who can grant permissions to this 
application on your behalf."},"operationResults":null,"timeStampUtc":"2018-05-25T13:59:07.7155381Z",
"clientRequestId":"c04dc78d-3127-4ff6-aae9-c59bdb5e4009","internalTransactionId":"71c3755c-0348-4ff7-8155-3d6b2b9c2fd2","
upn":
"tanmay@atcs.com","tenantId":"***,"userObjectId":null}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It looks like your app requires permissions which only an admin can grant. You'll have to ask your admin to go click the Grant permissions button in the portal for the app.

Answer (score 1):

Like @juunas said, There are some permissions which only a tenant admin can grant.
You can see those indicating a green checkmark under the 'Requires Admin' column in the permission selection page in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant permissions to your registered application using Azure portal as follows. Login to azure portal and go to the Azure Active Directory > App registrations > Click on your application > Settings > Required permissions > Grant permissions.